# Can I use a definite article although a listener don't know what it is?

Tags: sentence-structure, sentence-choice, sentence-usage

If there's the apple I bought yesterday, and I'm gonna eat the apple, can I say "I'm gonna eat the apple" although a listener don't know what apple it is?

For example, as in "I'm gonna go to the bank", I can say "the bank" although a listener don't know what bank I'm gonna go.

What about the apple?

Comment: Depends on the context. For example, "Did you give me the flowers?" (but the flowers are not given by the person you're talking to)--this sentence is still idiomatic because you *assume* your listener to know which flower you are referring to.

Comment: Regarding "the bank": in US English it's common to use the definite article with a lot of places - *the bank, the park, the library, the doctor's office*.  I would say this is because you already have a specific one in mind, and they're not interchangeable (unlike apples).

Comment: I think the bank can change into a bank.

Comment: "I'm going to a bank" sounds strange and non-fluent to me.  If someone said that to me, my reaction would be "What, you don't know which bank you're going to?  Just *a* bank?"

Comment: I think there's a case that if someone has to buy some oranges, so has to go to a shop, but hasn't yet decided which shop to go, someone has to go to a shop is the correct one.

Comment: Yes, that's true.  In the case of oranges, you might not have a specific shop in mind, so any shop that sells oranges will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of the definite article expresses the idea that *you* have a particular apple in mind. However, if you don't include additional information to orient the person you're speaking to, your remark will have the quality of a non-sequitur, as your listener won't have any idea which apple you're referring to, if you hadn't been talking about a particular apple.

Thus

> I'm going to eat the apple

would be unidiomatic if you had not been talking about a particular apple already as the remark contains no orienting information.

But

> I'm going to eat the apple I brought with me yesterday but didn't have time to eat because of the fire drill.

would be idiomatic if, say, your conversation had been about lunch generally, even though no apple had been mentioned yet. Presumably you are speaking to a colleague who was present for the fire drill, either that, or the use of the definite article with "fire drill" is a conversational gambit with a listener who did not know there had been a fire drill, who might then ask you "There was a fire drill?"

Comment: What about the bank? If so, the bank needs more information, isn't it?

Comment: You did not ask about a bank but about an apple. My intention is not to write  a book about the use of the article, which is what it would take to address the subject.  But with commonly visited locations (the bank, the post office, the park, the gas station) the definite article is used because your listener doesn't necessarily care or need to know which one you're going to, and is aware of the existence of these places and what goes on there. Suffice to say that *you* have a particular place in mind. Your listener is not disoriented by the article.

Comment: Really thank you!! I just wondered. No offense to you!

Comment: By the way, you said "unidiomatic", do you mean "formal"?

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with formality, but with the role of the article in conversation. The article orients the listener to the speaker's thought.

Comment: If the person you're speaking to is from out of town and has asked you for driving directions, they will definitely need to know which gas station you have in mind if you tell them "Turn left at the gas station" and there happens to be more than one gas station on the road.  In that case, gas station is not the generic place to get gas, but a particular landmark.